# AngularJS get the template or original expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I'm wondering if there is any way I can get the original `{{expression}}` after angular has complied the directives and interpolated the expressions. For instance if there is a text e.g. `Hi, Filip` and the user clicks on it, I want to be able to show a pop-up with `Hi, {{name}}`.

Now, one way I thought of doing that is by analysing the DOM before angular (e.g. during `run`) and then saving the expressions as additional attributes to the parent element. However, I run into various problems with that (e.g. if parent has other child elements and they are removed, e.g. with ng-if, then I can't reliably know which expression belongs to which text node).

Since Angular keeps `watchers` for these expressions, it must have a reference to the text nodes they are applied on. Is there any way I could access those?

The second question is, can I somehow get the original element of ng-repeat (before it was compiled and transcluded), for the similar purpose (allowing the user to modify it on-the-fly).

I want to avoid introducing new directives as this is meant to work on existing angular applications.

I'm not concerned about performance or security (i.e. this is not for production applications but rather for prototyping/debugging).

Comment: So if you have `<div>{{JSON.stringify(this.name, null, 2)}}</div>` you'd like access to the stringified (not evaluated) `"JSON.stringify(this.name, null, 2)"`?

Comment: Yes! (Although the example you provided would not be a valid Angular expression as JSON and this are not known inside Angular expressions)

Comment: im pretty sure you can invoke scoped functions in `{{}}` such as `{{this.method('foobar')}}`

Comment: anyway, you can store your expression logic in a factory and then stringify the factory to get its definition.

Comment: Yes, you can, but without `this`. You would just use `{{method('foobar')}}`.

Comment: What factory? Could you give a more concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

Use factories to supply to your html expressions with reusable logic. Assumes you're using `controller as` syntax so you can the controller's scope as `this` in your view.

```
// factory
function() {
  return 'bob';
}];

// in your controller
['somefactory', function(factory) {
  this.factoryString = factory.toString(); // => "function() {  return 'bob'; }"
  this.factory = factory;
}];

// view
<div>hi {{this.factory()}} you were made with {{this.factoryString}}</div>

// interpolated
<div>hi bob, you were made with function() { return 'bob' }</div>
```

I didn't test any of that though.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not what I'm looking for as this requires me to have the access to the controller. However, I want to be able to inspect any angular expression, not only the ones I created.

Comment: seems like a big security flaw if this were possible https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/interpolate.js#L130

Comment: I'm personally not worried about security (edited the post to state that) as this is meant as a add-on for prototyping/debugging, not for production applications.